# Issue with Angular Services with $broadcast and $on

Tags: angularjs

I am using Angular 1.3.15. with Angular Fire and FireBase.

I would like to pass data (a recipe) that I am receiving from a get request that is being held in the api controller to recipe controller that holds all recipes but I am having trouble. I set up a services module to handle the communication between the sibling controllers but I get back an error stating that addToRecipes() is not a function.

The Source Code can be viewed on Github on the recipeAdder2 branch: https://github.com/malissaromero/eatr/tree/recipeAdder2

api.html (Directive)

```
<h3>Let's Search Recipes</h3>
 <form ng-submit=fetchRecipes();>
   <input type="text" ng-model="recipe.search">
   <button type="submit">Submit</button>
 </form>

<h3>The Results</h3>
 <ul ng-repeat="result in searchResults">
  <li>
   <a href="">{{result.name}}</a>
  </li>
  <button ng-click="addToRecipes()">Add to Recipes</button>
 </ul>
```

recipe.html (Directive)

```
<div ng-repeat="recipe in recipes">
 <label>{{recipe.name}}</label>
 <label>{{recipe.ingredients}}</label>
 <label>{{recipe.directions}}</label>
</div>
```

recipe.js (Sibling Controller)

```
'use strict';

 angular
 .module('eatrApp')
 .controller('recipeCtrl', ['$scope', '$firebaseArray', 'recipeAdder', '$rootScope', function($scope, $firebaseArray, recipeAdder, $rootScope) {

  var firebaseUrl = "https://eatr.firebaseio.com";
  var recipeUrl = new Firebase(firebaseUrl + "/recipes")

  $scope.recipes = $firebaseArray(recipeUrl);

  $rootScope.$on('addToRecipes', function() {
    $scope.setRecipes.$add( recipeAdder.get() )
  });

  $scope.recipes.$loaded(function() {
    console.log("$loaded is on")
    if ($scope.recipes.length === 0) {
      $scope.recipes.$add({
        name: "PB&J Sandwich",
        ingredients: "Peanut Butter, Jelly, Bread",
        directions: "Put PB and Jelly on Bread."
      });
    }
  });

 $scope.reset = function() {
  $scope.recipe.name = "";
  $scope.recipe.ingredients = "";
  $scope.recipe.directions = "";
 };

 $scope.createRecipe = function() {
  $scope.recipes.$add({
    name: $scope.recipe.name,
    ingredients: $scope.recipe.ingredients,
    directions: $scope.recipe.directions
  });
  $scope.reset()
 };

}])
```

api.js (Sibling Controller)

```
angular
.module('eatrApp')
.controller('apiCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'recipeAdder', '$rootScope', function($scope, $http, recipeAdder, $rootScope) {

  $scope.searchResults = [];

  $scope.recipe = {
        search: ''
      }

  $scope.fetchRecipes = function() {
    $http.get("https://api.yummly.com/v1/api/recipes?", {
      headers : {
        "X-Yummly-App-ID" : "XXX",
        "X-Yummly-App-Key" : "XXX"},
      params : {
        "q" : $scope.recipe.search,
        "requirePictures" : "true"}
    })
    .then(function(response) {
      $scope.details = response.data;

      $scope.searchResults = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        var recipeName = response.data.matches[i].recipeName
        $scope.searchResults.push({name: recipeName})
      }
    });
  };

  $scope.addToRecipes = function(result) {
    console.log("add to recipes click event working")
    $scope.searchResults = [];
    recipeAdder.set(result, "setRecipes")
  };
}])
```

recipeAdder.js (Service)

```
angular
.module('eatrApp')
.service('recipeAdder', ["$rootScope", function($rootScope) {
  this.selectedRecipe = "";

  return {
    get: function() {
      return this.selectedRecipe;
    },
    set: function(value, list) {
      this.selectedRecipe = value;
      switch(list) {
        case "addToRecipes":
        $rootScope.$broadcast('addToRecipes', this.selectedRecipe)
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}]);
```

Comment: Use your service to load, store , modify and share collections. No need for events scattered all around to do this. Will find it a lot easier to manage all of this in one place. Then controllers will be really small with a few service methods and inherited arrays

Comment: @charlietfl Not sure what you mean? Am I scattering my events? I am trying to get my recipe controller to recognize the results in the api controller and adding the result to the recipes.

Comment: But you don't need that when your controllers and directives share the same arrays. Objects and arrays are passed by reference so whatever gets done in the stored collection in service would be reflected anywhere in app

Comment: @charlietfl Can you be more clear. Should I take out the services and just do a function in my api controller that adds results to the recipes and the recipe controller will just understand it because they are similar objects.

Comment: Explain this statement `$scope.addToRecipes.$add( recipeAdder.get() )` in `recipe.js`. In `apis.html` you have ` <button ng-click="addToRecipes()">`.

Comment: @georgeawg The first statement should be listening for the $broadcast in the service through($on) and pushing the results through($add) to recipes. 

The addToRecipes() click event is linked to 
`$scope.addToRecipes = function(result) {
    $scope.searchResults = [];
    recipeAdder.set(result, "addToRecipes")
  };`

Comment: Maybe you should use different names to avoid confusion.

Comment: @georgeawg Ok I renamed the function in api.js to 
`$scope.addToRecipes = function(result) {
    $scope.searchResults = [];
    recipeAdder.set(result, "setRecipes")
  };` 

and the function in recipe.js to 

`$rootScope.$on('addToRecipes', function() {
    $scope.setRecipes.$add( recipeAdder.get() )
  });`

Comment: And in my suggestion you would have the firebase methods, and stored arrays in service itself. Instead...you tell service to do an update, which then sends event to controller to also do an update. think of service as the `recipe store` ... and controllers/directives can connect to any part they need

Comment: @Charlietfl During my research, I have not seen services hold the functionality, only connection between controllers. Do you have a github repo where you did this that I can use as a reference?

Comment: Here's an example. Notice controllers only have a few lines of code and all the work and data is in a factory http://plnkr.co/edit/5pURfBAb7ELOgP9064Cc?p=preview